# restrict directory access Enhanced FTP Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sftp

Is it possible to restrict the access of an SFTP account to a certain folder/directory?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.
The way to restrict / split Marketing Cloud FTP access is by setting up up to three separate FTP accounts per BU in Setup.

Comment: This will still not differentiate between folders. Different FTP users still have access to the same structure.

Comment: Sure, that is what I meant with "That is not possible".
But help me understand now, maybe I'm on the wrong track. The different accounts, will they see the same folder content?

Comment: That’s correct @JonasLamberty - there is no separation of folders and data. So they all see the same content in e.g. import and export folders.

Comment: interesting. then i wonder what the point of having three accounts is, is it only for SSH?

Comment: You can revoke access for a single user, without replacing credentials in all integrated systems. Might be good when providing temporary access